# After I redirect to another page(from homepage to another tamplate) css doesn't load

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have problem with my css file loading for specific templates(every beside homepage).
The path for my css file is:
`Website/static/css/home.css`

and when I enter my webpage I'm starting at homepage where everything is okay, but then when I try to go to another page(for example mydomain.com --> mydomain.com/something/) the css doesn't load and in console I see this:
`http://example.com/something/static/css/home.css`

"Refused to apply style from 'http://example.com/something/static/css/home.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

and I don't understand why does it now look for static css in different root path(If that's a problem?).

What I use is django, aws-ec2:
my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_URL)
```

nginx conf:

```
    location /static/ {
         autoindex on;
         alias /home/ubuntu/Website/static/;
    }
```

homepage.html
   `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/home.css" />`

another template.html:

```
{% extends './homepage.html' %}
{% load static %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `href="static/css/home.css"` this is relative to the path of the current page.  it looks like you expect `/static/` to be the absolute path to static assets so that should be `href="/static/css/home.css"` with a leading `/`